# MySQl how to use multiple operator in one column

Tags: mysql

I am having a problem right now in MySQL. I'm trying to select a records without the subject called "Work Related" and "Business"
but the result is not right. Here's my syntax. Please help. Thanks

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tbl_questions WHERE function='Controlling the Operation' AND subject <> 'Work Related' AND subject <> 'Business' AND type <> 'Engine' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20
```

Comment: What does "the result is not right." means? Add sample data and the expected result.

Comment: the result still get the subject "Business"

Comment: Post sample records from the table and your expected records as output.

Comment: @CloudStrifez: May be there is a hidden space, leading or trailing, in the word `'Business'`. Check like `trim(subject) <> 'Business'` or `subject not like '%Business%'`.

Comment: @CloudStrifez Is is unclear what your problem is. We need sample records and the expected result to help you.

Comment: oh yes. the problem is the space. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * FROM tbl_questions WHERE subject !="Work Related" AND subject !="Business"
```

Comment: still the same, i can get a result "Business" in subject

Comment: put sample records for better under standing